# Как в VS Code быстро обернуть контент в тег?

Tags: visual-studio-code, теги, emmet

Как в VS Code быстро обернуть контент в тег?

Comment: `Shift+Ctrl+P` в открывшемся окне `Wrap`, после этого пишем нужный тег и все, оборачиваемый контент должен быть выделен

Answer (score 5):

1. Настройки Keyboard Shortcuts (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)
2. Устанавливаем горячие клавиши на "Emmet: wrap individual Lines with Abbreviation" у меня <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
3. Выделяем нужный фрагмент разметки жмем <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> или что там у вас и вводим наименование тега которым мы оборачиваем и жмем <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Горячие клавиши: "Wrap with abbreviation"

Answer (score 1):

Установите расширение "htmltagwrap".
Выделите фрагмент текста или кода.
Нажмите <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> for Mac).